# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

def get_alert(bid):
    # for simplicity I only provide "return" part
    return "1", "2"

get_alert_udf = func.udf(lambda bid:
       get_alert(bid),
       StructType(
                    [
                        StructField('prob', StringType()),
                        StructField('level', StringType())
                    ]
       )
    )

df = df \
    .withColumn("val", func.when(func.col("is_inside") == 1,
                                 get_alert_udf(
                                                func.col("building_id")
                                               ))
                            .otherwise(func.struct(func.lit("0"),func.lit("0")))
```

When I execute this code, I get the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 
u"cannot resolve 
'CASE WHEN (`is_inside` = 1) 
THEN <lambda>(building_id) ELSE named_struct('col1', '0', 'col2', '0') END' due to data type mismatch: 
THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type
```

In my case the outputs seem to have the same type in case of THEN and ELSE. I don't understand where is the difference between:

```
StructType(
                    [
                        StructField('prob', StringType()),
                        StructField('level', StringType())
                    ]
       )
```

and

```
func.struct(func.lit("0"),func.lit("0"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you use returns a named struct. This means that both names and types have to match:

```
func.when(
    func.col("is_inside") == 1,
    get_alert_udf(func.col("building_id"))
).otherwise(
    func.struct(func.lit("0").alias("prob"), func.lit("0").alias("level"))
)
```

or

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('prob', StringType()), StructField('level', StringType())
])

get_alert_udf = func.udf(get_alert, schema)
```

and then

```
func.when(
    func.col("is_inside") == 1,
    get_alert_udf(func.col("building_id"))
).otherwise(func.struct(func.lit("0"), func.lit("0")).cast(schema))
```